# Laravel: Logout/clear all sessions for all users from app

Tags: php, laravel, session

#### The Problem

I want to clear **all** sessions for **all** users in my Laravel application.

#### What I have tried

I understand that `Auth::logout()` will log out a single user, but not **all** users. I have also tried deleting the session files from `storage/framework/sessions`. Neither have worked.

I am using the built in [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) (e.g. `Auth`) and the file driver for sessions running Laravel 5.2.

How can I effectively force logout for all logged in users so they have to log in again?

Comment: deleting the session files should have been a good solution: i can't figure out how users sessions cloud be keep alive if session's files are deleted..

Comment: Tested this myself, and clearing all files in the sessions folder logged all users out of my application. Is there perhaps something else keeping them logged in?

Comment: @MattMcDonald, something must be keeping them alive because when I do it, they still pass the `Auth::check()` somehow...

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this?

Comment: I did not. I think I ended up renaming the session cookie or something to invalidate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's worth noting that Laravel actually only stores active sessions in the session folder; those that are 'remembered' but haven't been actively accessing your application do not count among these sessions.  As such, just deleting the files won't finish the job.

You must also clear all Remember Tokens from the users table, as this token is used in conjunction with the local token stored in the cookie to re-create the session when a user reconnects.

Comment: The "remember token" is exactly the issue. If you are *remembering* users, the combination of removing the session files and clearing the `remember_token` column in the users table will invalidate all previous sessions.

Comment: Agreed; for any other driver you'll want to clear whatever the associated storage area is, but I was attempting to answer the question which specified "File" driver.

Answer (score 5):

in app/session.php you can change cookie value, so user will automatically logout because of cookie is not match with the config

Comment: I had a similar problem changing my session to multiple domains. It happened that there was a conflict between the old and new cookie due to both having the same name but different domains. I'm not sure if that was the cause, but the consequence was that the user could not log in. On the login page, it was apparently a success, but he was redirected to it again instead of following the flow. The solution was to change the name of the cookie, add a check by the name of the old cookie and, if it exists, forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply regenerate the APP_KEY with following command.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will regenerate the APP_KEY, which will be used to encrypt and decrypt the cookies. Since it changes, all the cookies will be invalidated. Users has to login again.

Alternate:

You could also flush all cache by following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: It is by far the most Laravel specific answer