# Laravel 5 Destroy all user sessions and force logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to destroy all sessions? I need to logout all users and wondering if this is possible with astrisan?

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646902/laravel-logout-clear-all-sessions-for-all-users-from-app

Answer (score 11):

it's really depend on with session drive you picked.

- if you using file drive you can delete `storage/framework/sessions`
  path
- if you using database drive you can **delete all rows of session table**,
- if you using redis driver and also your cache driver is redis , you can run `php artisan cache:clear`

for any other driver you can do that like others.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by deleting all files under this path

```
storage/framework/sessions
```

Comment: if you delete storage/framework/sessions but not working ,here problem exactly in remember_token column in users table ,clear this column for all users and it will working .

Answer (score 2):

I know that I come little too late to the party but the easiest method to destroy all existing sessions is to change session cookie name. That way all sessions will be lost for existing users no matter what session storage you use and it won't affect anything else except your sessions.

In your .env file change or add this line:

SESSION_COOKIE="your_new_session_cookie_name"

Instead of "your_new_session_cookie" you can put anything you want as long it is different from the previous value. By default if this variable is not set laravel will use slugified version of "{APP_NAME}"_session" for session cookie name or "laravel_session" if APP_NAME variable is not defined.