# Force logout of all users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-artisan

How can I force all users to be logged out in a SPA? I want it so that when I deploy a new version, all users automatically get logged out.

I tried the following, but I'm not sure if it's the safest way to do it.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38155400/7009314 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693568/7009314

Comment: Flush all sessions. **Do not use `key:generate` because it will make any encrypted data you have generated invalid and you will not be able to recover them**

Comment: There's something really wrong with your application design in the first place if it is required to do so.

Answer (score 11):

If your session data is stored in the database, you need to clear the `sessions` table. Running a simple SQL query will solve the problem:

```
DELETE FROM sessions;
```

If you sessions are stored in files, then as @Karl suggests, you need to delete the session files from the filesystem:

```
rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/*
```

The name of the session cookie can also be changed to force all sessions to be invalid, but this is a code change rather than clearing data. The name can be updated in the `cookie` key in `config/session.php` file. This option is NOT recommended.

Answer (score 5):

You can destroy all the sessions. If you use Laravel Envoy to handle deployments, you can add the following line.

```
rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/*
```

If you're using the database session driver, clearing the sessions table is easy.

```
DB::table('sessions')->truncate();
```

Comment: Sessions table doesn't exist

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, the [SessionGuard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L483-L506) does a few things, and they are agnostic of the type of `SESSION_DRIVER` you have set in your environment.

So after reading some of the discussion on forums with Taylor and some other Laravel heavy-weights about why there isn't such a simple function, perhaps the best solution would be create a post-deploy `Job` or `Command` that you could run that would simply cycle through all users, so for whatever is Session is set. I'd try something like:

```
\App\User::each(function ($u) {
    Auth::login($u);
    Auth::logout();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's really depend on with session drive you picked.

- if you using file drive you can delete storage/framework/sessions
  path
- if you using database drive you can delete all rows of session
  table,

for any other drive you can do that like others.

You can also change cookie value in app/session.php, so user will automatically logout because of cookie is not match with the config

> It's worth noting that Laravel actually only stores active sessions in
>   the session folder; those that are 'remembered' but haven't been
>   actively accessing your application do not count among these sessions.
>   As such, just deleting the files won't finish the job.
>
> You must also clear all Remember Tokens from the users table, as this
>   token is used in conjunction with the local token stored in the cookie
>   to re-create the session when a user reconnects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating all user's remember tokens to blank and then flushing stored session and then modifying HomeController.

```
     \DB::table('users')->update(array(
    'remember_token' => '',
    'logout_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()));
    Session::flush();
```

Then in HomeController modify index function

```
    public function index()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $token = Auth::user()->remember_token;
        if ($token) {
            return view('home');
        } else {
            return redirect('/logout');
        }
    } else {
        return view('home');
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to share another way to achieve this, if the driver used is **file**.

This is the "pure" php way, so it could be a helper 'flush_sessions()':

```
$sessions = glob(storage_path("framework/sessions/*"));
foreach($sessions as $file){
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file);
}
```

It is safe to use this function? PHP will keep hidden files inside given directory (.gitignore)... so, try it out, it is safe.

It is worth to mention that if you put this inside a controller method, then **your session** will be restored after delete the file (apparently, Laravel will try to update the file after the request ends and if it doesn't exists, will re-create it). But all other sessions (users) will be logged out. If you run this code in php artisan tinker, for example, will not keep your own session file (because artisan runs with 'array' driver).

But, that is useful in my opinion. For example: if admin user wants to logout all users except himself.

For example:
You have two sessions:

[image: Two sessions]

After running the function, you have only one (the user that used it):
[image: One session]

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

//To Logout Specific user:

```
//$id == user id to to whom you want to logout
\DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(['remember_token' => null]);
\DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $id)->delete();
```

//To Logout All Users

```
$sessions = glob(storage_path("framework/sessions/*"));
foreach ($sessions as $file) {
if (is_file($file))
unlink($file);
}
//$id == user id to to whom you want to logout
\DB::table('users')->update(['remember_token' => null]);
\DB::table('sessions')->truncate();
```

No need to use sessions table operation if you are not using database as session driver.