# How to Force Logout all users from backend Admin Panel in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5.7

Im trying to force logout all logged users in website from admin panel .

for testing purpose i have logged in 3 different browsers , I have cleared all entries from `sessions` table from database , and then try to refresh page but user remains logged in like below :

[image]

and found new entries in `sessions` table

but i want like below , when force logout from backend .

[image]

> I want to force logout user and clear all sessions please guide me how to do it ?

Comment: Try to generate a new encryption key with `key:generate` artisan command, all cookies and sessions will be invalid.
I don't know if there is a better way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Logout/clear all sessions for all users from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646902/laravel-logout-clear-all-sessions-for-all-users-from-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `remember_token` column in your `users` table, you might want to update that one as well:

```
DB::table('users')->update(['remember_token' => null]);
```

Comment: i got 419 session expired  on first time login , after force logout , why this happen ?

Comment: `remember_token` is when the user logs in and selects the Remember me option on the login form.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved using below function :

```
use DB;

public function force_logout(){
        DB::table('users')->update(['remember_token' => null]);
        DB::table('sessions')->delete();
}
```

Comment: Good job on putting someone else suggestion as your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can check every time in middleware if status is false.
logout user and redirect to login.
and also check in login basic logic

```
if (Auth::user()->active == 0) {
   Auth::logout();
   return redirect()->route('admin.login');
}
```